# How to keep same DataAnnotations behavior when migrating from Newtonsoft to System.Text

Tags: c#, json.net, asp.net-core-webapi, system.text.json

I'm migrating a webapi (.NET 8) that uses Newtonsoft.Json to System.Text.Json. Everything was going smoothly until I stumbled into some differences related to the "required" keyword.

I will try to show it using the WeatherForecast default .NET sample:

**Program.cs**

```
 // code omitted for brevity
 builder.Services.AddControllers();
 // code omitted for brevity
```

**WeatherForecast.cs**

```
public class WeatherForecast
{
    public DateOnly Date { get; set; }

    public int TemperatureC { get; set; }

    public int TemperatureF => 32 + (int)(TemperatureC / 0.5556);

    [Required]
    public required string Summary { get; set; }
}
```

**WeatherForecastController.cs**

```
// code omitted for brevity
[HttpPost(Name = "WeatherForecast")]
public IActionResult Post(WeatherForecast request)
{
    return Ok(request);
}
```

Using swagger if I invoke the Post endpoint without passing the Summary property in the body like this:

```
{
  "date": "2024-01-01",
  "temperatureC": 1,
}
```

I get a 400 and this error message:

```
"errors": {
    "$": [
      "JSON deserialization for type 'NewtonsoftVsSystemTextLab.WeatherForecast' was missing required properties, including the following: summary"
    ],
    "request": [
      "The request field is required."
    ]
  },
```

On the other hand, if I use Newtonsoft, simply by adding this extension method to this line in Program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();
```

I get the user-friendly error message from DataAnnotations:

```
"errors": {
    "Summary": [
      "The Summary field is required."
    ]
  },
```

Is there a way to get the same behavior using System.Text.Json that does not require adding intrusive changes to the source code?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change :

```
   [Required]
    public required string Summary { get; set; }
```

into:

```
    [Required]
    public string Summary { get; set; }
```

Then get the same behavior using System.Text.Json :

[image]

Comment: We want to keep using the "required" keyword as it prevents non-initializations at compile time.

Comment: Hi @EduardoBrites ,From [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/required-properties) we can see "If one or more of these required properties is not present, the JsonSerializer.Deserialize methods throw a JsonException.".

Comment: Yeah, the thing is that Newtonsoft seems to ignore the "required" keyword which is fine for us.

Comment: Hi @EduardoBrites , System.Text by design to check "required" property value.  The System.Text.Json throws an exception if the JSON payload doesn't contain a value for the marked property.  It's the easy way to move the required to avoid the exception. If you don't want this, you can use  Newtonsoft  or custom model binder and custom validation.

Comment: Besides, there is a way to specific the response body , but it can only check one required.